# Regular Expression to check if the URL is under a particular domain

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regular expression that finds if the given URL is under my website.

For example :

```
http://www.my_domain.com/internal_page should give true.
www.my_domain.com/internal_page should give false.
http://www.my_domain.com should give false. ( should have a "/" after .com  ).
http://www.my_domain.com:dfdf should give false.
```

--
Thank you

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the pattern you want,

```
  $pattern = "#^https?://www.my_domain\.com(/.*)?$#";

  $test    = 'http://www.google.com';

  if ( preg_match( $pattern, $test ) )
  {
      echo $test, " <strong>matched!</strong><br>";
  } else {
      echo $test, " <strong>did not match.</strong><br>";
  }
```

Comment: Hey Man i am Vinoth Babu only...Kovai (child adoption) :)

Comment: Da .. therinju pochu :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
http:\/\/www\.my_domain\.com\/.*
```

you should really to show some efforts before posting.

- `http:\/\/` - means http://
- `www\.my_domain\.com` is equal to www.mydomain.com
- `\/.*` means / and 0 or any characters in the end of expression.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
http:\/\/www\.my_domain\.com\/(.+)
```

It passes the four tests you gave

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this

```
 $url = "http://www.my_domain.com/internal_page";
 $host = "www.my_domain.com";
 if(strpos($url, "http://".$host."/") === 0){
      // we have a winner
 } else {
      // no good
 }
```